# ruby on rails css and assets not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Similar questios have been asked, but I cant fix my problem.
I am trying to link my html to css with asset pipeline and it's not working. There are no errors, the code is compiled to html, but it's just plain text on white background, instead of using style from style.css. I should probably change something in config files, but I dont know what exactly.

in my html file I have:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'applicaton' %>
```

and in application.css I have:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

I want to include file assets/stylesheets/style.css

When ruby code is compiled, html looks like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/applicaton.css" />
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it's not working".

Comment: oh, sorry. There are no errors, the code is compiled to html, but it's just plain text on white background, instead of using style from style.css

Comment: it's the same if I try to use image_tag, so I guess it must be something wrong with asset pipeline.

Comment: Thank you.  I would update your question with this information so more are likely to be able to help you.